# Closure and Sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

[image]

I dug this example out of Chen's free online source notes.

I am very puzzled by the last comment

*but the limit $\mathbf{a}$ does not belong to $\ell_0$.Hence the linear subspace $\ell_0$ is not closed in $\ell^\infty$*

I don't understand the idea. To show a subset $\ell_0$ isn't closed in $\ell^\infty$, should you find a sequence in $\ell_0$ that doesn't converge in $\ell^\infty$? Not the other way around? Or generally speaking isn't this true for any metric space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following result is used here:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and $F$ be a subset of $X$. If $F$ is closed, and $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of elements of $F$ which converges to some $x\in X$, then $x\in F$.

(so by closed it means that "we can't escape by limit")

Comment: Then what about my definition? I am guessing I am wrong then?

Comment: Oh wait if the limit point isn't in the set, it can't be in the subset.

Comment: But it also works to find a sequence that also converges outside of $\ell^\infty$ right? Abeit it may not be the easiest thing to do

Comment: How could a sequence converge outside $\ell^\infty$? The limit will necessarily lie in $\ell^\infty$ (use the definition with $\varepsilon=1$).

Comment: Can't the nth term of the sequence lie just on the boundary of the set?